# COUNT non-empty cells in each column of a table with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with list of names on each rows and 20 columns with values but some are blanks.

this code is for summing all the values depends on the name `{=SUMPRODUCT((IF($I$3:$I$370=AG3,$J$3:$AC$370,"")))}`

But how can I just count if there's a value in cell? Can the above code be used to count? or give me Idea what to use. Thanks. :)

EDIT:

example. `AG3` match in `I3`,`I10`,`I100` then I need to count values in `J3:AC3`,`J10:AC10`, and `J100:AC100`.

Comment: did you look at COUNTIF and COUNTIFS

Comment: this one gives me error `=COUNTIFS($I$3:$I$370,AG3,$J$3:$AC$370,"<>"&"""")` even changing the second condition with "*" or some values it gives error.

Comment: Use =COUNTA to count the filled cells and use =COUNTBLANK to count the blank cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=H2)*(B2:F7<>""))
```

Where:

A2:A7 is your name column

H2 is your name equal to criteria

B2:F7 is there non blank cells you want to count

[image]

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks! I was thinking I needed to put `IF` inside. Learned something new. :)

Comment: also does not need to be an array now either

Comment: Yes,much better. Thank you. Can you help me understand why my above formula is adding up while yours is counting? if its against the rules to ask here no need to answer. Thank you again, Sir.

Comment: mine is counting because its only looking at true or false situations.  True is 1 and false is 0 when converted by a math operation in excel.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I understand it now. :)